# MySQL Workbench 6.2: Missing closing parenthesis

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have the following query which is giving an error:

Error: Missing 'Closing Parenthesis'.

```
SELECT geomfromtext('polygon(('CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(a.latitude ,' ', a.longitude),'11.12345 66.65432')'))')
FROM  GeometryTable a
```

This is the final query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM GeometryTable a 
WHERE 
mbrintersects
(
    geomfromtext('polygon(('CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(a.latitude ,' ', a.longitude),'11.12345 66.65432')'))'),
    geomfromtext('polygon((11.59679 79.50852,12.89778 76.51863,12.89096 76.5176,11.59679 79.50852))')
);
```

Comment: Maybe this? SELECT geomfromtext(
CONCAT('polygon((',GROUP_CONCAT(a.latitude ,' ', a.longitude),'11.12345 66.65432))'))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select geomfromtext(CONCAT('polygon(',GROUP_CONCAT(a.latitude,' ',a.longitude),'11.12345 66.65432)'))
FROM  GeometryTable a
```

Comment: Don't know why the final query is not working? After editing with your answer. Error ` Invalid use of group function`.